Children's book about boy who dies and then wakes up in other childrens' bodies
This was a children's book, or maybe for young teens. I found it in 2014 but it looked older so maybe it was written in the early 2000s or even later.
It was about a boy who falls off a cliff and passes away. His mother (who was maybe a scientist) buries him in some sort of acid which gives him the ability to wake up in different childrens' bodies. He had his teacher's phone number and would ring her every time he woke up. One day he woke up in the body of a a child who had an abusive father who cursed at him.
I’m not sure if I ever finished the book as that’s all I remember.

This SF question points to Levithan's "Every Day" https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/76794/looking-for-a-serial-body-swapping-story-that-is-not-levithans-every-day

Thank you for answering, it’s not that book unfortunately. I found my book in a primary school when I was quite young so I feel like it had to have been aimed towards children. I remember the main character dying and him being buried in that acid at his funeral so he’s not in a coma. Thank you again for answering, I’ve been looking for years and this has gotten me a little closer. @AdamBurke

Hey @coverslutjonald note that Levithan's book is different to the Egan short story I mention in my separate answer. "Every Day" is a YA novel I am not familiar with, but seemed like a useful lead. Also welcome to Lit SE : )

Some of the features of this are shared with the Greg Egan short story, "The Safe Deposit Box", first published in 1990. It is about a person who wakes up in a different body each day. It is slowly revealed (spoiler) ...

 ... that all the people whose bodies they occupy are in the same locality, and the main character is a patient in a coma at a hospital.

It is not aimed at children or teens, and some of the other details do not match.
